# Emacs scala-mode newline-and-indent weirdness

Tags: emacs, scala

I have the following code in Emacs under scala-mode (from the Scala 2.8 package):

```
object t1 {
  def main (args: List[String]) = {
    println("Hello")
  }
}
```

I also have my return key set to `newline-and-indent`. When I repeatedly hit return after the last brace, it goes to the leftmost column for one blank line. When I press return again, it *indents* two spaces. Then it stays at this indentation thereafter. Obviously it shouldn't do this.

However, when I repeatedly run `newline-and-indent` by the M-x and typing `newline-and-indent`, I don't get the two-space indentation. The same goes for `reindent-then-newline-and-indent`.

Why is there this difference?

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is stemming from the fact that you rebound `enter` to `newline-and-indent`, which doesn't seem to be idiomatic when using `scala-mode`.  `newline-and-indent` ends up calling `indent-according-to-mode`, which checks for some undesirable settings, works around them if necessary, and if everything is OK, ends up calling `indent-line-function`, which is a buffer local variable.

Since this is mode-specific, modes define their own `indent-line-function`.   Most have pretty consistent behavior, but Scala's function is `scala-indent-line`, seen here:

```
(defun scala-indent-line ()
  "Indent current line as smartly as possible.
When called repeatedly, indent each time one stop further on the right."
  (interactive)
  (if (or (eq last-command this-command)
          (eq last-command 'scala-undent-line))
      (scala-indent-line-to (+ (current-indentation) scala-mode-indent:step))
    (let 
    ((indentation (scala-indentation)))
      (scala-indent-line-to indentation))))
```

The funny thing about this is that it detects repeated calls and indents further over each time.  When using M-x, `last-command` is not `scala-indent-line`, it's `execute-extended-command`.  So, when using M-x, it continues to indent at the correct indentation level.  When bound to a key, however, it notices it was executed immediately previously and indents an extra level.

The effect isn't cumulative...I think this is because of the odd command set at the end of the function, which initially indents the line, but then checks for the correct indentation with `(scala-indentation)` and indents accordingly.

I'm not 100% on this, but at first glance that's what seems to be going on.

Comment: Well then the solution be to not let it into that code path. The following works:


            (local-set-key [return] '(lambda ()
                                       (interactive)
                                       (setq last-command nil)
                                       (newline-and-indent)))))